# Tesseract couldn't load any languages problem

Tags: c++, linux, tesseract

I search on internet and I try change my TESSDATA_PREFIX to export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/share/tessdata or ...share/tessract-ocr/4.00 or 5/tessdata and tesseract/tessdata** this paths is not working for me. I have eng.traineddata file on all this locations. But I'm still getting this error and I try change traineddata file from github. But I'm still getting this error.

Here is my code

```
#include <string>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
cv::Mat image;
string outText;
image = cv::imread("text.png",cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
api->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY);
api->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
api->SetImage(image.data, image.cols, image.rows, 3, image.step);
outText = string(api->GetUTF8Text());
cout << outText;
api->End();
    
}
```

My Makefile

```
CC = g++
PROJECT = main
SRC = main.cpp
LIBS = `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4 tesseract`
$(PROJECT) : $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(SRC) $(LIBS) -o $(PROJECT)
```

Here is the error message

```
Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Estimating resolution as 304
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Hey, are you sure your environmental variables have double quotes? such as; TESSDATA_PREFIX="/user/local/share/tessdata"

Comment: You are not checking the return value of Tesseract Base API functions like Init. Ignoring return values is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the first parameter in `Init()` method to specify the file path that "eng.traineddata" located
and set the 3rd parameter to `OEM_DEFAULT`
before :

```
api->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY);
```

as to :
ex)

```
api->Init(C:\tesseract\tessdata, "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
```

[image: tessdata folder path]